# FORD FIESTA 1.4 YEAR MODEL 2013

Tags: ford, starting, electronics, fiesta

We vacuumed the car with a lighter-connected car vacuum cleaner- all of a sudden wipers and dash light went grazy- unplugged vacuum cleaner but now although dash lights come on- car wont start

Comment: You turn the key and nothing happens? Have you checked the fuses to ensure they're good?